# ssh & ftp time out. Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out

Tags: systemd, sshd, gui, proftpd, logind

I have a relatively old debian server running Jessie 8.11

```
uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.57-2 (2018-07-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Recently after restarting my machine I cannot start my GUI.  Normally after the machine is booted it goes to the command line prompt. I logined and then run

`startx`

but after a long wait it showed an error page and I am back to the command prompt. I check the log file `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[603073.109] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[603073.112] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[603073.113] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[603073.114] Current Operating System: Linux debian 3.16.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.57-2 (2018-07-14) x86_64
[603073.114] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-6-amd64 root=UUID=5adf53d2-1fb6-4cf7-a383-76ac90e75a74 ro quiet
[603073.116] Build Date: 14 October 2017  10:41:31AM
[603073.117] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1+deb8u2 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[603073.118] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[603073.120]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
[603073.121] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[603073.125] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Oct  3 10:22:31 2019
[603073.144] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[603073.164] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[603073.164] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[603073.164] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[603073.164] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[603073.165] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
Using a default monitor configuration.
[603073.165] (==) Automatically adding devices
[603073.165] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[603073.165] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[603073.176] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[603073.176]    Entry deleted from font path.
[603073.193] (==) FontPath set to:
/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
built-ins
[603073.193] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[603073.193] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[603073.194] (II) Loader magic: 0x559cb876bd80
[603073.194] (II) Module ABI versions:
[603073.194]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[603073.194]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[603073.194]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[603073.194]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[603073.194] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[603073.195] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0102:8086:2017 rev 9, Mem @ 0xfe000000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[603073.195] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[603073.212] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[603073.294] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.294]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[603073.294]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[603073.295] (==) AIGLX enabled
[603073.295] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[603073.295] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[603073.295] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[603073.295] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[603073.295] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[603073.295] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[603073.295] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[603073.301] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[603073.330] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.330]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 2.21.15
[603073.330]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[603073.330]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[603073.330] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[603073.330] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[603073.343] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.343]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.9.0
[603073.343]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[603073.343]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[603073.343] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[603073.344] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[603073.352] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.352]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 0.4.4
[603073.352]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[603073.352]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[603073.352] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[603073.352] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[603073.360] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.360]    compiled for 1.15.99.904, module version = 2.3.3
[603073.360]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[603073.360]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[603073.360] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, HD Graphics,
HD Graphics 2000, HD Graphics 3000, HD Graphics 2500,
HD Graphics 4000, HD Graphics P4000, HD Graphics 4600,
HD Graphics 5000, HD Graphics P4600/P4700, Iris(TM) Graphics 5100,
HD Graphics 4400, HD Graphics 4200, Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200
[603073.364] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[603073.364] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[603073.364] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[603073.364] (++) using VT number 1

[603073.364] (--) controlling tty is VT number 1, auto-enabling KeepTty
[603073.370] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[603073.370] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[603073.370] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[603073.370] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[603073.370] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[603073.371] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.371]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.0.2
[603073.371]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[603073.371] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[603073.371] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[603073.371] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[603073.371] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[603073.371] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[603073.371] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 2000
[603073.371] (**) intel(0): Relaxed fencing enabled
[603073.371] (**) intel(0): Wait on SwapBuffers? enabled
[603073.371] (**) intel(0): Triple buffering? enabled
[603073.371] (**) intel(0): Framebuffer tiled
[603073.371] (**) intel(0): Pixmaps tiled
[603073.371] (**) intel(0): 3D buffers tiled
[603073.371] (**) intel(0): SwapBuffers wait enabled
[603073.371] (==) intel(0): video overlay key set to 0x101fe
[603073.385] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): EDID for output VGA1
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer: SNY  Model: 2400  Serial#: 16843009
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Year: 2005  Week: 9
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.300 V
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Sync:  Separate  Composite
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 34  vert.: 27
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Gamma: 2.20
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): redX: 0.644 redY: 0.338   greenX: 0.267 greenY: 0.622
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): blueX: 0.140 blueY: 0.084   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Supported established timings:
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 720x400@70Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 640x480@60Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 640x480@72Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 640x480@75Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 800x600@60Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 800x600@72Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 800x600@75Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Supported standard timings:
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): #0: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 960  refresh: 60  vid: 16513
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Supported detailed timing:
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): clock: 108.0 MHz   Image Size:  338 x 270 mm
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1328  h_sync_end 1440 h_blank_end 1688 h_border: 0
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): v_active: 1024  v_sync: 1025  v_sync_end 1028 v_blanking: 1066 v_border: 0
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Ranges: V min: 48 V max: 75 Hz, H min: 28 H max: 81 kHz, PixClock max 145 MHz
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Monitor name: SDM-HS75
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): Serial No: 1613329
[603073.398] (II) intel(0): EDID (in hex):
[603073.398] (II) intel(0):     00ffffffffffff004dd9002401010101
[603073.399] (II) intel(0):     090f01030c221b78eae5e5a456449f23
[603073.399] (II) intel(0):     155054adcf0081808140010101010101
[603073.399] (II) intel(0):     010101010101302a009851002a403070
[603073.399] (II) intel(0):     1300520e1100001e000000fd00304b1c
[603073.399] (II) intel(0):     510e000a202020202020000000fc0053
[603073.399] (II) intel(0):     444d2d485337350a20202020000000ff
[603073.399] (II) intel(0):     00313631333332390a202020202000c8
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA1
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 491 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 connected
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 using initial mode 1280x1024
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[603073.399] (II) intel(0): Kernel page flipping support detected, enabling
[603073.399] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[603073.399] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[603073.399] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[603073.399] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[603073.401] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.401]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[603073.401]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[603073.401] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[603073.401] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[603073.401] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[603073.401] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[603073.401] (II) Unloading modesetting
[603073.401] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[603073.401] (II) Unloading fbdev
[603073.401] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[603073.401] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[603073.401] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[603073.401] (II) Unloading vesa
[603073.401] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[603073.411] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[603073.411] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[603073.411] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 1280x1024 stride 5120, tiled
[603073.418] (II) UXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[603073.418] (II)         solid
[603073.418] (II)         copy
[603073.418] (II)         composite (RENDER acceleration)
[603073.418] (II)         put_image
[603073.418] (II)         get_image
[603073.418] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[603073.418] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[603073.423] (II) intel(0): Initializing HW Cursor
[603073.423] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[603073.423] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[603073.423] (==) intel(0): Intel XvMC decoder enabled
[603073.423] (II) intel(0): Set up textured video
[603073.424] (II) intel(0): [XvMC] xvmc_vld driver initialized.
[603073.424] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 Enabled
[603073.424] (==) intel(0): hotplug detection: "enabled"
[603073.436] (--) RandR disabled
[603073.442] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[603073.563] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[603073.563] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[603073.564] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 338 x 270
[603073.874] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[603073.874] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[603073.874] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[603073.874] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[603073.901] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[603073.901]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 2.9.0
[603073.901]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[603073.901]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[603073.901] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[603073.901] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[603073.901] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[603073.901] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[603073.901] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[603073.901] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[603073.901] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input6/event3"
[603073.901] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[603073.901] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[603073.902] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[603073.902] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[603073.902] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[603073.902] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[603073.902] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[603073.903] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[603073.903] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[603073.903] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[603073.903] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[603073.903] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[603073.903] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input5/event2"
[603073.903] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[603073.903] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[603073.903] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[603073.903] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[603073.904] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event0)
[603073.904] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[603073.904] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PixArt USB Optical Mouse'
[603073.904] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[603073.904] (**) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[603073.904] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x93a Product 0x2510
[603073.904] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[603073.904] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[603073.904] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[603073.904] (--) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[603073.904] (II) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[603073.904] (II) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[603073.904] (**) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[603073.904] (**) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[603073.904] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:093A:2510.0001/input/input3/event0"
[603073.904] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PixArt USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[603073.904] (II) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[603073.904] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[603073.904] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[603073.904] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[603073.904] (**) PixArt USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[603073.905] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PixArt USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[603073.905] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.905] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603073.905] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell Dell USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[603073.905] (**) Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[603073.905] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Dell Dell USB Keyboard'
[603073.905] (**) Dell Dell USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[603073.905] (**) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[603073.905] (--) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x413c Product 0x2003
[603073.905] (--) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Found keys
[603073.905] (II) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[603073.905] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:413C:2003.0002/input/input4/event1"
[603073.905] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell Dell USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[603073.905] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[603073.905] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[603073.905] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[603073.906] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event5)
[603073.906] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.906] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603073.921] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[603073.922] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.922] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603073.922] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event8)
[603073.922] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.922] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603073.923] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event9)
[603073.923] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.923] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603073.923] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event10)
[603073.923] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.923] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603073.924] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[603073.924] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.924] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603073.925] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event4)
[603073.925] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[603073.925] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SNY", prod id 9216
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[603219.328] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[603219.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[603219.329] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SNY", prod id 9216
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[603244.567] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[603276.956] (II) evdev: Dell Dell USB Keyboard: Close
[603276.956] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[603276.956] (II) evdev: PixArt USB Optical Mouse: Close
[603276.956] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[603276.956] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[603276.956] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[603276.956] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[603276.956] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[603276.990] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

The real problem, however, is that from that time on, when I connect to this server using ssh, it takes a very long time (25 seconds).

```
tail -f auth.log
 Oct  3 10:12:05 debian sshd[28144]: Accepted password for tempuser from 192.168.1.168 port 56112 ssh2
 Oct  3 10:12:05 debian sshd[28144]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user tempuser by (uid=0)
 Oct  3 10:12:14 debian systemd-logind[28141]: Failed to enable subscription: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out
 Oct  3 10:12:14 debian systemd-logind[28141]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
 Oct  3 10:12:30 debian sshd[28144]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Activation of org.freedesktop.login1 timed out
 Oct  3 10:12:39 debian systemd-logind[28154]: Failed to enable subscription: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out
 Oct  3 10:12:39 debian systemd-logind[28154]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
```

And when I connect using FTP, it waited so long that FileZilla eventually timeout and I cannot connect at all.

```
tail -f auth.log
 Oct  3 10:13:55 debian proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session opened for user tempuser by (uid=0)
 Oct  3 10:14:19 debian systemd-logind[28183]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
 Oct  3 10:14:19 debian systemd-logind[28183]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
 Oct  3 10:14:20 debian proftpd: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to create session: Activation of org.freedesktop.login1 timed out
 Oct  3 10:14:20 debian proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session opened for user tempuser by (uid=0)
 Oct  3 10:14:44 debian systemd-logind[28230]: Failed to enable subscription: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out
 Oct  3 10:14:44 debian systemd-logind[28230]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
 Oct  3 10:14:45 debian proftpd: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to create session: Activation of org.freedesktop.login1 timed out
 Oct  3 10:14:45 debian proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session closed for user tempuser
```

I tried as I read from other posts to do the following

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
 Job for systemd-logind.service failed. See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

I suspect `org.freedesktop.login1` has something to do with the fact that I cannot load a GUI? Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem miraculously disappeared after I updated dbus package

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dbus
```

Now the GUI is back and ssh & ftp login no longer time out.